# blocking 117.0.0.0/8 shows as having blocked localhost

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to block some foreign ip traffic to our webserver.  [Arin.net](https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-117-0-0-0-1/pft?s=117.50.7.159) shows that the block 117.0.0.0/8 belongs to South Brisbane Australia.  But when I block it, it shows up as "localhost/8".

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -s 117.0.0.0/8 -j DROP -m comment --comment "south brisbane au"
```

the result from the listing of `iptables -L --line-numbers` is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       all  --  localhost/8          anywhere             /* south brisbane au */
```

What's going on here?  Why is 117.0.0.0/8 showing up as "localhost/8"?  Will this block affect any traffic to localhost?

### UPDATE (and output of accepted solution)

I implemented using `-n` as suggested by several including the accepted answer.  Here is the output after using `-n`:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n --line-numbers | head
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       all  --  117.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0            /* south brisbane au */
```

---

*An added benefit is that, `iptables -L` had gotten tremendously slow.  I had not had time to look into it; but avoiding the dns lookups also solved that problem. Obviously, the dns lookups on the source were making `iptables -L` very very slow with more than a handful in the chain.  It now emits the complete 144 in that chain immediately.  It seems odd that reverse lookup for the source is the default.*

Comment: The ARIN report just means that APNIC is the registrar responsible for that block (check the "Comments" section): you need to do a [`whois` search](http://viewdns.info/whois/?domain=117.50.7.159) using APNIC to find out who owns the specific address range (in this case, supposedly an ISP in China.)

Comment: Also, what does `iptables -n -L --line-numbers` show?

Comment: reverse lookup or similar humanize-the-numbers is turned on by default for a bunch of things (`tcpdump`, `lsof`, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a false alarm caused by

```
% host 117.0.0.0
0.0.0.117.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer localhost.
```

the owner of the relevant reverse DNS zone putting a "localhost." record on that address. There's a flag to `iptables` to turn off DNS lookups (`-n`). This will also make the command run faster as no time is wasted on said lookups.

If you need the owner of that zone use `dig` as that will show the `SOA`. You'll need to use the reverse address form (which `host` or other lookup tools will return):

```
% dig 0.0.0.117.in-addr.arpa
...
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
0.117.in-addr.arpa.     86266   IN      SOA     dns1.vietel.com.vn. tuananh.viettel.com.vn. 2008010803 10800 3600 604800 86400
```

Comment: beautiful ... that and being a number transposition from 127 made me wonder wether the OP had made a typo.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I guess you could troll other admins by putting funny records on the (typically unused as they were once for broadcast) `.0` addresses. Like `iptables-error` or such...

Comment: https://www.itworld.com/article/2808533/hardware/stuck-in-nslookup-.html